# Using mod_rewrite to prepend a directory name to relative path

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to redirect clients requesting http://www.example.com to http://www.example.com/moodle.

This can be easily achieved by placing a html file in www root which redirects incoming requests to specified address. Though I want to get this going with mode_rewrite rules.

I've tried few simple configuration but have either ended up in a loop or some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your configuration:

```
Alias /moodle /var/www/moodle
<Directory /var/www/moodle>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

and fit the configuration between "Directory" to your needs.

[Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) for more information